# Replacing Percent Ranges to be Labeld "Above 50% and "Below 50%" Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, replace

[image: Table comparing attendance rates to improvement on test scores as Yes/No1]

I am using Google Sheets.
I have a snippet of the data I am trying to compare. I want to make a two way table that compares Attendance to Improvement in scores.

A table such as:
[image]

I am unsure of how to replace the percentages with the labels with "Yes" (Meaning attendance was above 50%) or "No" (Attendance below 50%) and create the two columns needed to create the table. Attendance Above 50% Yes/No, Improvement Yes/No

Answer (score 0):

I have to make some assumptions here.
A) That your data in column A (pink) is formatted to display as percentages. ie. the underlying data is numeric.
B) Your table expects numbers in the Improved/Not Improved fields.

If that's the case then `COUNTIFS` would help.

Improved:

```
=countifs($A:$A,">0.5",$B:$B,"Yes")
=countifs($A:$A,"<0.5",$B:$B,"Yes")
```

and Not Improved

```
=countifs($A:$A,">0.5",$B:$B,"No")
=countifs($A:$A,"<0.5",$B:$B,"No")
```

[image]